CSS grid reverse column issue
I've created an element using grid that has an image with a text box overlay and it works really well, but I want to be able to reverse it too.
  .FB06 {
  
    display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 5rem 34rem 10rem;
    grid-template-columns: 5rem 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 5rem;
  }
  
    .FB06-image {
  
      grid-row: 1;
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: -1;
      object-fit: cover;
      height: 100%;
  
      &.FB06-image-rightify {
        grid-column: 6/span 3;
      }
    }
    
    .FB06-contents {
  
   grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 4 / span 3;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    padding: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    &.FB06-contents-leftify {
  
      
    grid-column-start:1;
        }
    
    }

So the rightify/leftify classes are to reverse it. The contents block works fine, but the image is what I'm having trouble with. To get it to start at the last column and then essentially span backwards. With 6/span 3 it is instead creating new columns on the fly, rather than spanning existing columns. I'm not sure how to do it and any guidance would be appreciated. Also below is a screenshot of how the block looks as standard (not reversed)

Thanks

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You know how many columns there are, and how many it spans so start it from the end less the span ( maybe 3 / span 3)
